# What's the difference between "nicht" & "nicht mehr"?

Tags: negation

What's the difference between the following sentences:

> - Wir hatten uns schon länger nicht mehr gesehen.
> - Wir hatten uns schon länger nicht gesehen.

**EDIT** - another example:

> - Viele der alten Krankheiten plagen uns heute nicht mehr.
> - Viele der alten Krankheiten plagen uns heute nicht.

Answer (score 2):

I guess, this is a duplicate, but could not find the earlier question.

---

There is no difference in respect to the long time span you didn't see each other. The *nicht mehr* variant implies however, that you used to meet quite frequently earlier.

(I can't provide a satisfying reference for this right now.)

---

In the second example *nicht mehr* reflects the expectation, that this also holds for the future, while *nicht* only refers to the current moment.

Comment: +1. Good point about the distinction of how things used to be earlier.

Comment: But, the thing is, if it wasn't someone I see quite often, I wouldn't even bother telling him/her "Hey, we haven't seen each other for quite some time"

Comment: @KeN SmilePachI: This kind of thing is fairly common in English, there's even an idiom "Long time no see."

Comment: @RDBury yeah but how would that translate in German? with "nicht mehr" or only "nicht"?